PID Controller for Linear and Angular Velocity of A Vehicle Using Torque as Input For Wheels
When implementing a PID controller for a skid-steer vehicle, I am able to reach a constant linear velocity using PID, but when angular velocity is added to the equation with its own PID, my results are not good. What is the formula for combining linear and angular velocity of the vehicle?
The formula I use for the calculations is :
V_left_wheel = V_forward - yaw_rate * d/2

V_right_wheel = V_forward + yaw_rate * d/2

Where d is distance between wheels, yaw_rate is the target angular velocity, and V forward is forward velocity of the vehicle. This formula does not work. I tried multiple PID combinations where I have a PID for yaw rate, velocities of the wheels- forward velocity of the vehicle etc.
Is there any other formula that I can use, as I feel like the formula is what is limiting me. I am in a simulation environment where I have access to current velocities of the vehicle, and to control velocity I apply torque to each wheel independently.
